# Python wildcard in the middle of a string

Tags: python

I have a directory with a number of files which all have the same basic filename format (below is a sample)

```
roll_0_oe_2008-03-24_AAA.XNGS
roll_0_oe_2008-03-24_AAB.XNGS
roll_1_oe_2008-03-31_AAC.XNGS
roll_1_oe_2008-03-31_AAG.XNGS
roll_2_oe_2008-04-07_AAR.XNGS
roll_2_oe_2008-04-07_AAJ.XNGS
```

I am trying to select a file based on using:

```
filename = 'roll_'+str(roll)'_'*ID
```

where roll is an int that I convert to a string and ID is a string.  I'm using the wildcard * for the _oe_date element as i don't care about this part. I however get the following error:

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

How can I construct a filename using  wildcard in the middle?

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. I think you want `filename = 'roll_'+str(roll) + '_' + ID`.

Comment: Didn't you mean `+` instead of `*` ?

Comment: `*` needs to be in a string, at the moment you're using it as a multiplier.

Comment: See also [**`fnmatch`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to embed the wild card *as a character*, and make sure that you're file search interface accepts wild cards.

```
filename = 'roll_'+str(roll)'_*'+ID
```

However, note that this does *not* identify a specific file name: to do that, you need a system command (there are several to search and fetch file names).  The Python **open** function does *not* accept wild cards.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html?highlight=glob#module-glob) module, and the `str.format(...)` method:

```
# Don't know where this comes from.
roll = 2
id = 'AAC'

# Format: roll_2_oe_2008-04-07_AAJ.XNGS
Fn_format= "roll_{}_oe_*_{}.XNGS"

# Make a file-glob by putting the roll into format.
rolled_files = Fn_format.format(roll, id)


import glob

for fname in glob.iglob(rolled_files):
    print("Rolled file:", fname)
```

Comment: Thanks Austin, How would I add the ID element to Fn_format (I need to pass the ID (AAA or AAG etc) into the filename? Thanks

Comment: Add another `{}` in the right place in the format string, and call `.format(roll, id)`. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) for a LOT about format strings.

Comment: Probably "roll_{}_oe_*_{}.XNGS", if I understand correctly.

Comment: Edited to add `id`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `format()`:

```
filename = 'roll_{}_{}'.format(roll, ID)
```

Comment: Thanks Jan, how would I include the date element into the filename?